# How to make the site scroll smoothly with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar

I found a smooth scrolling site. All elements move very smoothly. I googled for a long time, but did not even find a similar example. Any ideas how this can be repeated? https://www.sweetpunk.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is likely using a library similar to [`locomotive-scroll`](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) to achieve this effect. See here for a demo: https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

There is a css property that's does something similar

```
*{
scroll-behaviour:smooth;
}
```

Comment: scroll-behavior